# Is "poor" in "he was born poor" and adverb or an adjective?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Is "poor" in "he was born poor" an adverb or an adjective?

And could the answer be related to the answer to this question? 
["I was born in 1961" is ‘born’ past participle or an adjective here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609169/i-was-born-in-1961-is-born-past-participle-or-an-adjective-here)

Comment: Usually it is an adjective: "He was poor when he was born" as an antonym of "he was born with a silver spoon in his mouth". But you might find people who use it as an adverb, perhaps: "His birth was badly administered".

Comment: I would say adjective; “born” acts like a quasi-copula here.

Comment: It doesn't describe the action of being born, it describes the person. So it's an adjective.

Comment: "born" is a verb. The adjective sense is found in phrases like "s German-born philopher" or "He's a born musician".

Comment: Compare "born free", "died happy". I'm sure I saw a similar question recently but can't find it...

Comment: This is from a book of grammar exercises, which includes the solutions at the end. The book claims that "poor" is an adverb, and they say the same of "best" in "best known [author]" and "most" in "most translated [author]".

Comment: Why was this migrated from English Stack Exchange to Language Learners? Aren't we all language learners? Is this an obvious one for the native speakers if everyone here is disagreeing with a grammar book written by English language speakers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic mistake of mixing up part of speech and function in clause structure. While *poor* is a modifier in clause structure, it's still an adjective. Not everything that functions as modifier in clause structure is an adverb; though some grammars and dictionaries take that view, it falls apart under close analysis and serious grammarians have mostly abandoned it.

> He was born...
>
> poor [AdjP]
>
> in the hospital [PP]
>
> Monday morning [NP]
>
> naturally [AdvP]

All of the above are modifiers, but have different part of speech classifications depending on their head word.

Comment: Nice choice of NP there. Before I read it I'd been expecting a simpler choice like *king* instead, but yours is much better since even with transitive verbs nobody could confuse it for the verb's object.

Comment: Then maybe grammar books for middle school should steer away from this kind of stuff. Especially when it's contested. Thanks for your example. It's funny that in a related discussion I've been told that anything that attaches to a verb (and even an adjective) is an adverb, by which metric this seems like an adverb to me just as well.

Comment: What is the "classic mistake" to which you refer? The question section doesn't opine an answer, it merely poses the question. Are you referring to the position taken by the grammar book I mentioned in the comments?